# Unable to to install "GSImageViewerController Pod" and unable to use its code in project in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, cocoapods, uitapgesturerecognizer

I need tapped image in full screen for that one of the developer suggested this [GSImageViewerController pod](https://github.com/wxxsw/GSImageViewerController)..

if i install the pod only like `pod "GSImageViewerController"` this and "import GSImageViewerController" in swift file in my project

and like documentation said i have written below code

```
import UIKit
import GSImageViewerController
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tapImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    tapImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tapImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{

    let imageInfo   = GSImageInfo(image: tapImage.image!, imageMode: .aspectFit)
    let imageViewer = GSImageViewerController(imageInfo: imageInfo)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(imageViewer, animated: true)
}
}
```

**for imageview controller i have added navigationcontroller.. so here if i tap on image then image coming in full screen.. but like documentation said here if i tap anywhere in the screen or drag out the image then i am unable to go back to original position why?? where am i wrong??? please do help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `push` you should do `present`. Below is a working example from my project.

```
let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: profileImageView.image!, imageMode: .aspectFit)
let transitionInfo = GSTransitionInfo(fromView: profileImageView)
let imageViewer    = GSImageViewerController(imageInfo: imageInfo, transitionInfo: transitionInfo)
present(imageViewer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: cant we use this in tableviewcell?, my profile img in cell

Comment: if i am trying `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: (cell?.imageView?.image)!, imageMode: .aspectFit)`.     in selector func.      got error.    `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value:`

Comment: instead of creating a new instance you need to get the current cell. let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexpath ... use that .. search on web and you will find the answer